# How to replace text in NetBeans using regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, netbeans

How can I replace text in NetBeans using regular expressions?

For instance,

I want to replace these texts below,

```
$item->article_id
$item->title
$item->content
...
```

with

```
$item['article_id']
$item['title']
$item['content']
...
```

I tried with this below in the input field of '**Containing Text:**'

```
$item->(.*)
```

But **no match found**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with: `$item->(.*?)` does that do the trick for you?

Comment: nope. still the same. no match found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write special characters, like `$` sign in the *Find what* input, you must escape it with `\` (backslash). But you don't need replace the `$` sign with another `$` sign.

In *Find what*:

```
item->(.*)
```

In *Replace with*:

```
item['$1'];
```

Then press replace all. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to match the content.

```
item->([a-z]*...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
item->([a-z]*)
```

or

```
item->(.*)
```